# AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I was trying to install this module named `pyautogui`, but when I typed in the terminal `pip install pyautogui` (and also `py -m pip install pyautogui`), well i found this:

```
File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\lib2to3\pgen2\grammar.py", line 95, in load
    d = pickle.load(f)
AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'load'
```

Apparently there is no `load` function defined when it actually is, in the line 43 of the file `picle.pyi`, so I don't know if this has to do with something with the file type, or the version, but I didn't found any answer anywhere.

Does someone know why this could be happening?

Comment: You should edit your question with more information like versions etc.  Is this python3?  Should you be using pip3?

Comment: try uninstalling the package and reinstalling it might work its a bug that occurs sometime if not you might have had another file that has the name pickle.py

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have named one of your files `pickle.py`?

If so, you'll need to rename that into something else so that python will not get the modules mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself because it was a kind of a new problem, so in the `pickle.pyi` file was this script:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
 DEFAULT_PROTOCOL: int

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    # TODO: holistic design for buffer interface (typing.Buffer?)

    class PickleBuffer:
        # buffer must be a buffer-providing object
        def __init__(self, buffer: Any) -> None: ...
        def raw(self) -> memoryview: ...
        def release(self) -> None: ...

    _BufferCallback = Optional[Callable[[PickleBuffer], Any]]

    def dump(
        obj: Any, file: IO[bytes], protocol: Optional[int] = ..., *,
        fix_imports: bool = ...,
        buffer_callback: _BufferCallback = ...
    ) -> None: ...
    def dumps(
        obj: Any, protocol: Optional[int] = ..., *,
        fix_imports: bool = ...,
        buffer_callback: _BufferCallback = ...
    ) -> bytes: ...
    def load(
        file: IO[bytes], *, fix_imports: bool = ..., encoding: str = ...,
        errors: str = ..., buffers: Optional[Iterable[Any]] = ...
    ) -> Any: ...
    def loads(
        data: bytes, *, fix_imports: bool = ..., encoding: str = ...,
        errors: str = ..., buffers: Optional[Iterable[Any]] = ...
    ) -> Any: ...
elif sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    def dump(obj: Any, file: IO[bytes], protocol: Optional[int] = ..., *,
             fix_imports: bool = ...) -> None: ...
    def dumps(obj: Any, protocol: Optional[int] = ..., *,
              fix_imports: bool = ...) -> bytes: ...
    def load(file: IO[bytes], *, fix_imports: bool = ..., encoding: str = ...,
             errors: str = ...) -> Any: ...
    def loads(data: bytes, *, fix_imports: bool = ...,
              encoding: str = ..., errors: str = ...) -> Any: ...
else:
    def dump(obj: Any, file: IO[bytes], protocol: Optional[int] = ...) -> None: ...
    def dumps(obj: Any, protocol: Optional[int] = ...) -> bytes: ...
    def load(file: IO[bytes]) -> Any: ...
    def loads(string: bytes) -> Any: ...
```

Basically what that means is that it depends on what version you are using, the functions will be different, the problem is that I was using `python3.9` and since is the newest version of python it wasn't updated.

So the solutions are:

a. Find a way that the scripts works with the newest version (which I didn't found btw)

b. Just change the python interpreter to a lower version

And sry for those who tried to help me because I know I should have given more information about my problem, so a new lesson learned today.